# PicklingError on pp module of python

Tags: python, module, pickle, parallel-python

I'm using the pp module of python.
What I need to do is run in parallel the "fmin" function of "scipy.optimize".
I'm importing fmin like this:

```
from scipy.optimize import fmin
```

Next, I'm defining a function which executes the fmin function like this:

```
def fitting():
v = fmin(e, v0, args=(x,y),maxiter=10000, maxfun=10000)
return v
```

And for this to run in parallel I'm using:

```
job5 = job_server.submit(fitting, (e, v0, x, y,), (fitting,), ("scipy.optimize",))
v = job5()
```

Then I get a PicklingError in module of job5. That is "scipy.optimize" I guess.
I also tried `import scipy.optimize as sth` but job_server.submit does not accept "sth" as a module.
Any solutions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `from scipy.optimize import fmin` import line into the `fitting` function directly, and stop passing it into `submit`.

Comment: The error I get is still
"PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed"

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with `pp` very easily.  However, if you use `dill` and the fork of `pp` that is in `pathos` (i.e. `pathos.pp`) then it works in most cases.

See several examples in the `mystic` optimization package, which provides parallel and distributed optimization using extensions of the scipy optimizers.

For example, this works with both `pathos.multiprocessing` and `pathos.pp`:
https://github.com/uqfoundation/mystic/blob/master/examples/buckshot_example06.py

The above code launches several `fmin_powell` instances in parallel, which can give you pseudo-global optimization with steepest-descent speeds.

Get the code here: https://github.com/uqfoundation